# IIS Canonical Domain Name with Exception for internal domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I've got a site in IIS that has 2 domain bindings associated with it:
- mysite.com
- internal.mysite.com

The users inside the network user the internal.mysite.com and outside uses mysite.com.

I'd like to setup a canonical domain name rule so the outside users going to mysite.com are redirected to the www version (www.mysite.com).

But, when I setup the redirect, the internal.mysite.com users are also directed to the www site.

Is it possible to create an exception so that the internal.mysite.com domain is NOT redirected?  Or, do I have to create a separate site in IIS?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="Redirect example.com to www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

You just need to replace `example.com` with your actual domain name